# In a coupled pendulum, how is the equation of motion described

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, physics, mathematical-physics

This is from Hobson, Riley, Bence Mathematical Methods problem 9.1

The question is: 
[image]

There is a hint given: 
[image]

If someone could just help me understand the physics part, I can try to do the calculations alone. What exactly is shown in this image? Are these hanging masses attached by springs if so why is the motion perpendicular to each other and not towards each other? What are these formulas above representing? I see a Force on the left but I don't recognize the right side. Why is no equation of energy represented like $\frac{mgx_1^2}{2l}+\frac{mgx_2^2}{2l}+\frac{1}{2}k(x_2-x_1)^2$

---

I found the answer to my problem and it turns out this is a harder problem to understand than to solve. The equation comes from the [Lagrangian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics#Lagrange_multipliers_and_constraints) of the formula for kinetic and potential energy treating the variables and derivatives as independent of time. The derivation of the formula can be found [here](http://csirnetphysics.blogspot.mx/2012/11/classical-mechanics-question-1.html).

.

Comment: It's an above picture of swinging pendulums connected by strings, these are the eigenmodes of the system associated with the eigenfrequencies. If you look at a pendulum from above it looks like a mass swinging across a center line

Comment: It doesn't make physical sense to me. Are the weights interacting only when the weights reach their vertex and the string becomes taught?

Comment: Yes the strings mediate the interaction via a springlike action

Comment: Well the interaction is there as long as two masses are displaced wrt each other as the interaction is proportional to the distance between them...it's just weaker as they begin to swing in phase

Comment: @triatticus What force does the term cmx represent?

Comment: It is the gravitational force, likely that $c=\dfrac{g}{L}$, this is the restoring force of the pendulum

Comment: @Triatticus ok, assuming $\theta\approx sin\theta$ that c makes sense.

Comment: It's a big hint. The system moving in a normal mode, all the masses oscillate at the same frequency, that's why they are eigenstates of the matrix for the forces. Further, every possible state of motion is a linear combination of normal modes. The second mode has $\omega^2=c$. $$$$ You can solve the equations of movement by means the equation for the energy or the equations for the forces. Often, the equation for the forces is the preferred one. In the case for the energy, you'll see all terms squared e.g. $cmx_1^2/2+d(x_1-x_2)^2/2+\dots$

Comment: @RafaBudría lol that is really funny! They left the auto label "label 2" for the second mode. Thanks :)

Comment: :) You are welcome.